# Utilizar CTE (Common Table Expression) cria um tipo de "cache" no banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, cte

Tenho uma consulta com diversos `JOIN` e sub-queries, e quando executada, leva por volta de 7 segundos para retornar.

Obtendo o mesmo resultado, utilizando CTE's, a consulta demora por volta de 8 segundos da primeira execução, mas as próximas vezes (*não consegui saber o intervalo disso, mas são algumas horas*) a consulta é retornada em menos de 1 segundo.

---

#### Dúvidas

- Quando utilizo **CTE's**, o banco de dados cria um tipo de cache?
- O que seria relevante, na escolha da utilização, entre JOIN's e SUBQUERIES's ou CTE's?

Comment: Qual o sgbd usado?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Que usei em questão, é SQLServer 2008 R2, de um sistema ERP. São diversas tabelas, diversos joins, cases, cálculos, etc. O que fiz foi praticamente separar etapas por CTE.

Comment: Ele tem uma ferramenta que permite ver o plano de execução, mas exatamente agora não posso enviar print pois estou no celular. Também tem uma alteração na execução da consulta que mostra o que foi de fato executado, possibilitando encontrar gargalos e até mesmo sugerindo índices para melhorar a consulta

Comment: Opa, legal isso aí... Depois posta pra gente!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quando utilizo CTE's, o banco de dados cria um tipo de cache?

Não, esses conceitos não estão relacionados. O *cache* é criado conforme a necessidade por uma série de circunstâncias. Claro, o CTE pode aproveitar o que está no cache, pode colocar coisas coisas no cache e aproveitar depois, mas isso é circunstancial e ocorre como efeito colateral, não por o CTE depende disto.

Você pode ter obtido um resultado diferente por várias razões, pode ser porque a consulta consegue ser melhor processada, melhor planejada com mais detalhes. Mas é claro que o *cache* pode estar influindo também. São variáveis demais para afirma sem saber o caso concreto em detalhes.

Se não souber fazer o teste pode estar colhendo uma informação falsa.

> O que seria relevante, na escolha da utilização, entre JOIN's e SUBQUERIES's ou CTE's?

A pergunta não faz muito sentido. Tem que usar o que for mais pertinente com o que precisa e o que dá melhor resultado no caso específico, e nem está restrito a estas 3 formas, que sequer são antagônicas. De forma geral é possível fazer qualquer coisas sem essas 3 coisas, mas pode ser mais fácil ou mais otimizado escolher um deles em certo cenário.

A pergunta fala em cenário exemplo, mas ela não tem exemplo algum, tem um resultado que nem se sabe como foi obtido.

Comment: Realmente não há cenário exemplo, até tirei. Na verdade eu ia colocar, mas é muito grande e extremamente particular de um sistema, então não seria útil. Acredito que o que mais deve ter afetado foram os JOIN's, que são muitos, e por CTE, acabam ficando mais "leves" por serem executados em uma "sequência", certo!? Mas o "estranho" é como com CTE reduziu de forma extremamente significante por um certo tempo. Acho que teria que montar um cenário teste para ir a fundo nisso. Quando der tentarei fazer.

Comment: Isso, ele organiza melhor, dá mais contexto. De fato, é extremamente complicado testar sem dar resultados falsos.